Files libpixbufloader-jpeg.so, libpixbufloader-png.so missing in libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 installation
I have a problem with libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0.
I need it for running an AppImage. On my Ubuntu 20.04 system, everything works fine. But when I try to run it on Ubuntu 22.04 or Linux Mint, there is always the following Gtk-Warning:

(AppRun.wrapped:11464): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:59:52.686: Could not load a pixbuf from icon theme.
This may indicate that pixbuf loaders or the mime database could not be found.
**
Gtk:ERROR:../../../../gtk/gtkiconhelper.c:494:ensure_surface_for_gicon: assertion failed (error == NULL): Failed to load /usr/share/icons/Yaru/16x16/status/image-missing.png: Unrecognized image file format (gdk-pixbuf-error-quark, 3)
Bail out! Gtk:ERROR:../../../../gtk/gtkiconhelper.c:494:ensure_surface_for_gicon: assertion failed (error == NULL): Failed to load /usr/share/icons/Yaru/16x16/status/image-missing.png: Unrecognized image file format (gdk-pixbuf-error-quark, 3)
Aborted (core dumped)

It's because the system can not find the Loader-File (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/) "libpixbufloader-png.so". In the installation directory, the files ibpixbufloader-jpeg.so libpixbufloader-png.so are missing. There is also no entry in the loaders.cache file for png and jpeg.
I tried to reinstall libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 but it was reinstalled without the missing loaders. I also tried
$ sudo /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders --update-cache

and the same from snap
$ sudo /snap/gnome.../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders --update-cache

but the two files are still missing.
Thank you for help!
